# Horrible performing RAID

Tags: nginx, raid, hardware-raid, glusterfs, megaraid

I have a small GlusterFS Cluster with two storage servers providing a replicated volume. Each server has 2 SAS disks for the OS and logs and 22 SATA disks for the actual data striped together as a RAID10 using MegaRAID SAS 9280-4i4e with this configuration: http://pastebin.com/2xj4401J

Connected to this cluster are a few other servers with the native client running nginx to serve files stored on it in the order of 3-10MB.

Right now a storage server has a outgoing bandwith of 300Mbit/s and the busy rate of the raid array is at 30-40%. There are also strange side-effects: Sometimes the io-latency skyrockets and there is no access possible on the raid for >10 seconds. The file system used is xfs and it has been tuned to match the raid stripe size.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason for such a bad performing array? 22 Disks in a RAID10 should deliver *way* more throughput.

Comment: I suspect your client is calling sync() a lot, which forces the array to wait until it's committed the write and disables write caching. Do you have a NVRAM write cache anywhere?

Comment: Did you disable XFS's barriers?

Comment: @pjc50 For testing I've disabled all write access on the servers. This also happend when there was no write at all on the RAID.

Comment: @pfo I did not but it looks like I should to this. However, as stated in my previous comment this also happens if there are no writes at all. :/

Comment: Which kernel version are you running?

Comment: @pfo Just upgraded today to 3.2.13 with grsec. Before that I was running 2.6.38 also with grsec. It happened on both kernels.

Comment: How large is the RAM of the machine and what are the values for vm.{dirty_ratio,dirty_background_ratio,dirty_writeback_centisecs}?

Comment: Also use blktrace(8) to see if your CDBs contain a lot of FUA or SCSI_CACHE_SYNCHRONIZE commands sent to the device.

Answer (score 3):

Is someone [shouting to your hard drives](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDacjrSCeq4)? :-)

More seriously: is there lots of write activity during I/O latency spikes? Have you tried to use `iotop` and/or `btrace` to see what's going on under the hood?

Perhaps the RAID controller flushes its cache during the spikes and blocks everything until it completes?

Comment: Maybe I should ask for a webcam in the datacenter :-)
I have disabled all writes on the system for testing purposes. There still were this latency spikes :/

Comment: Are those spikes happening at predictable times (like, once an hour) or just randomly?

Comment: I haven't noticed any patterns yet. The strange thing is that the freqency of these spikes don't increase with more load.

Comment: Next thing you tell me you have Western Digital Caviar Green drives (which tend to have such odd performance problems due brain-dead power-saving features etc).

Comment: I have Seagate drives.

Answer (score 0):

If you can log a spike, we'd have more to work with. Either way, with no glaring configuration issues, I'm reasonably confident in saying that this is probably a hardware issue. I'd start by replacing the card, and then maybe the disks if they're under warranty.